# Can I use "to demand" with an object, I demand smt. from

Tags: word-usage

Is it correct to use the verb *to demand* with an object like this:

> He is **demanding** *my father* to pay him $600. (Seinfeld TV show)

I have not seen this kind of usage in the dictionaries. I have found only "an outraged public demanded *retribution*." But the object here is *what* they demanded, not *the person* they demanded it *from*.

Comment: I would expect "He is demanding that my father pays him $600."

Comment: I know the meaning. I asked whether it is a correct usage or not.

Comment: The “demand ... to” construction (that is, *demand* followed by an infinitive as an indirect object) is so wrong that I have trouble believing the quote is correct.  Do you have a link to video or a transcript for the quote?

Comment: I've found out, it is actually without "to" -- "He is demanding **my father pay** him $600."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically demand some action. "I demand you leave this house at once", "They demanded that the governor resign", etc.

You can demand an object, like "The customer demanded a refund" or "Hitler demanded the Sudentenland". In such a case the person is demanding that the thing named be given to him, so in a sense you're still demanding an action.

The wording in the example is odd. As kiamlaluno says, a more common wording would be, "He is demanding my father pay him $600" or "He is demanding that my father pay him $600." In either case, he is demanding an action. Saying, "my father to pay him" is a little odd because we don't normally put an infinitive in there.

But in any case, it's still quite common to demand an action.